# I can't access the text in the span using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hi Everyone receive error msg when executing this code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import html.parser
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
response = session.get("https://www.imdb.com/chart/boxoffice/?ref_=nv_ch_cht")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.find_all("tr")

for table in tables:
    movie_name = table.find("span", class_ = "secondaryInfo")
    print(movie_name)
```

output:

> movie_name = table.find("span", class_ = "secondaryInfo").text
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: It didn't find the element that's why you have a `NoneType`

Comment: The code you posted does not have the `.text` so it works fine and prints the first table entry along with the other entries. The first entry is `None` which does not have any attributes including `text`. You could just add an `if` statement like `if movie_name:` and conditionally print your text.

Comment: can you please show me how ? I didn't fully understand your solution :)

Comment: first use `find()` without `.text` and next `if movie_name: print( movie_name.text )`

Comment: BTW: error shows that you use `find(...).text` but you show code `find(...)` without `.text` - better check what you really run.

Answer (score 0):

You selected for the first row which is the header and doesn't have that class as it doesn't list the prices. An alternative way is to simply exclude the header with a css selector of nth-child(n+2). You also only need `requests`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

response = requests.get("https://www.imdb.com/chart/boxoffice/?ref_=nv_ch_cht")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

for row in soup.select('tr:nth-child(n+2)'):
    movie_name = row.find("span", class_ = "secondaryInfo")
    print(movie_name.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to grab `CSS` selector by clicking on the desired element in your browser without inventing anything superfluous. However, it's not working perfectly if the HTML structure is terrible.

You're looking for this:

```py
for result in soup.select(".titleColumn a"):
    movie_name = result.text
```

Also, there's no need in using `HTMLSession` IF you don't want to persist certain parameters across requests to the same host (website).

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Cant-access-the-text-in-the-span-using-BeautifulSoup#main.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# user-agent is used to act as a real user visit 
# this could reduce the chance (a little bit) of being blocked by a website
# and prevent from IP limit block or permanent ban
headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}


response = requests.get("https://www.imdb.com/chart/boxoffice/?ref_=nv_ch_cht", headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

for result in soup.select(".titleColumn a"):
    movie_name = result.text
    print(movie_name)

# output
'''
Eternals
Dune: Part One
No Time to Die
Venom: Let There Be Carnage
Ron's Gone Wrong
The French Dispatch
Halloween Kills
Spencer
Antlers
Last Night in Soho
'''
```

---

P.S. There's a [dedicated web scraping blog](https://dev.to/dimitryzub) of mine. If you need to parse search engines, have a try using [SerpApi](https://serpapi.com/).

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.